# Hosting a Tumblr blog on Amazon Web Services as subdomain

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, tumblr, amazon-route53

How do I use a custom (sub)domain (or secondary page) on AWS to 'host' a Tumblr blog?

I'm using Amazon S3, CloudFront, and Route 53 to host a static website. The static news/blog section I've made lives under http://wavefrontbiometric.com/news.html. So far, so good.

Now I've set up a blog/news page on Tumblr (so http://wavefrontbiometric.tumblr.com) that I want to have replace http://wavefrontbiometric.com/news.html. I understand that this might need to change to a two-level structure http://news.wavefrontbiometric.com/), and that's fine.

So far I've tried following [these instructions from Tumblr](https://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/custom_domains), but with no luck. I've added a 'Hosted Zone' on Route 53 for http://news.wavefrontbiometric.com/, but failed to point the C-NAME record to 'domains.tumblr.com'.

Basically I'm using Tumblr as a backend for the news page only. Users shouldn't be able to notice any visual difference from any other page. I've already got my HTML & CSS markup perfected.

Any help is much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: It would help if you could include the real domains you are using.

Comment: Hi @mikedidthis. The real domain is http://wavefrontbiometric.com. Currently the static news page is at http://wavefrontbiometric.com/news.html. The Tumblr is http://wavefrontbiometric.tumblr.com. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only interaction between Tumblr and your (sub)domain is Route53. No other services are needed. Your subdomain should be a CNAME as shown in the instructions; if that isn't working, something is wrong in your Tumblr configuration, which is outside the scope of stackoverflow.

Comment: Thanks @tedder42. It's definitely an issue with my Route53 setup, as I haven't changed anything on the default Tumblr configuration. Should I be creating a CNAME record set within the domain, or creating a whole new hosted zone for the subdomain? Thanks.

Comment: you want a CNAME within the domain.